# Best way of mixing code and html/content in JSX

Tags: reactjs

In a render method I have something like this:

```js
<tr><td>Reason</td><td>
  {
      if (@props.result?.job?.result?.reason?)
       @props.result?.job?.result?.reason
      else
        "-"    
   }
</td></tr>
```

(In CoffeeScript)

It doesn't see right to me to mix the output (the text) with the code inside the {}

However the React docs seem to suggest that they favour this:

We've found that the best solution for this problem is to generate HTML and component trees directly from the JavaScript code such that you can use all of the expressive power of a real programming language to build UIs. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html

So. Is this right? Or is there a slightly better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example by prashant is correct. Since `JSX` seems very similar to `HTML` IMHO its wrong to use conditions and iterations in `JSX`. Doing this will not only reduces readability & will cause issues extending/modifying existing code. You could modularise the JSX elements using ES6 class methods and where conditions responsible for that Group of JSX elements can be handled.

[**Here**](https://web-design-weekly.com/2015/01/29/opinionated-guide-react-js-best-practices-conventions/) is better guide for handling this in JSX.

It is upto individuals choice but taking it one step further you can in many places avoid `JSX` all together (which will be insane amount of code) or mix and match JSX/No JSX. Example code from [react-without-jsx](https://github.com/ustun/react-without-jsx)

```
const React = require('react');
const {div, h1, ul, li, a} = React.DOM;

const MyElement = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return div({style: {color: 'red'}},
                   h1(null, 'Hello ' + this.props.name),
                   ul(null,
                      li(null, a({href: "http://cnn.com"}, "CNN")),
                      li(null, a({href: "http://bbc.com"}, "BBC"))));
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. For those who don't want to follow the link the solution proposed is to do your conditional test at the top of the render method and set a variable accordingly and then use that in the body of the code where it outputs the html.

Comment: @JustinWyllie actually that is also a bad idea have a look at this [cached-state-in-render](https://github.com/planningcenter/react-patterns#cached-state-in-render)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to separate HTML in JSX from `If-else` statement or general code. Well, you can make a different function which only has HTML and render it according to `if-else` condition. E.g.-

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>Reason</td>
      <td>
        { this.props.results ? this.renderWhenTrue() : this.renderWhenFalse()}       </td>
    </tr>
    )
},

renderWhenTrue: function() {
  return (
    <span> Whatever HTML, when True </span>
  )
},

renderWhenFalse: function() {
  return (
    <span> Whatever HTML, when False </span>
  )
}
```

Use Ternary operator and call respective functions. return Whatever HTML you need from these functions like `renderWhenFalse` or `renderWhenFalse`.